# Given an MST for an edge-weighted graph, how can you find the minimally weighted path from x to y?

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm, undirected-graph

I have an edge-weighted undirected graph represented by a minimum spanning tree. Each vertice is represented by an integer. The MST looks like this:

I wonder, how can I use this MST to find the shortest path from a vertex x to a vertex y? Say I want to find the shortest path from 0 to 3. It's easy to see that the path is 0-2, 2-3 with total weight 0.26+0.17 = 0.43. But how should I construct a general way of doing this? in pseudocode

```
edge           weight
6-2            0,40
4-5            0.35
5-7            0.28
2-3            0.17
0-2            0.26
1-7            0.19
0-7            0.16
```

Comment: There should be only one path (it's a tree), and it's not necessarily the one that would have been shortest in the full graph, so I'm not sure what you want to do

Comment: @harold I was under the assumption that the tree would contain all the smallest paths from any vertice to any other vertice.

Comment: It doesn't work like that unfortunately, an MST has minimal *total* weight, for example in the [MST on the corresponding wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) the two nodes in the bottom left have an edge of length 9 between them in the original graph and that edge is the shortest path, but that edge isn't in the MST.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since you are given an MST you only know that the total edge weights in the graph are minimal. However, a path between two nodes in an MST does not guarantee that it is the minimal path between those two nodes on the actual graph. In order to find the minimally weighted path from node x to node y, you can perform Dijkstra's Algorithm on the original graph (not the MST). Dijkstra's can find the minimum distance from a starting node, in this case, x, to every other node in the graph.

Perform Dijkstra's Algorithm as follows and store the information in a table:

1. Begin at the starting node, x in this case and go to the node with the least weight from x
2. From the lowest weight node just visited, explore the neighbors and again pick the edge with the lowest weight
3. Sum up the total cost so far from the edge you are visiting. If you started at x, then visited a, then c, find the total distance from x to a to c.
4. If the weight to a node is lower than what was previously recorded, update the value in the table because now a shorter path has been found.

Ultimately, after performing this algorithm, the table should contain the lowest weight path from x to y.

Answer (score 0):

The MST does not necessarily contain the shortest path from one vertex x to another vector y. The minimum spanning tree is a tree that has found the minimal path for every node to be visited. This does not necessarily mean that the shortest path from x to y is included in the MST. To find the true shortest path from x to y you would have to run an algorithm to find the shortest path on the original graph, like Dijkstra's.